# Clickable emails in Label

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qml, ubuntu-sdk

In my app (ite-missa-est) and in the sudoku-app we are wondering how to make an email clickable as a URL link is. In a label the code for a link is:

```
    Label {
        //TRANSLATORS: here is the context
        text: i18n.tr("Bugs and traductions: ") + "<a href=\"%1\">Launchpad</a>".arg("https://launchpad.net/ite-missa-est")
        onLinkActivated: Qt.openUrlExternally(link)
    }
```

What is the code for an email? it might be very close.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you are looking for, but this functionality is not yet available. The link to use would probably be `mailto:email@example.com`, but until [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-ui-toolkit/+bug/1184969) is fixed there's not much you can do, unfortunately.

Comment: Just to be clear, because I am not sure we understand each other. The code above, to open "https://launchpad.net/ite-missa-est", works. The problem is only for emails.

Comment: Is the Ubuntu Touch web browser actually launched to open the URL?

Comment: No on testing it on a desktop, it works. That is all.